# How to order records from one table by repetitions of column value by from second table

Tags: mysql

Table `user_contest_image`:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| filename | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table `image_vote`:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| image_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ip       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`image_vote.image_id` is foreign key to `user_contest_image.id`.
I am trying to get all records from `user_contest_image` and order them by the repetitions of the related `image_vote.image_id`.

Example data:

```
user_contest_image

id  user_id  filename     title
1   1        image_1.png  imageTitle1
2   2        image_2.png  imageTitle2

image_vote

id  image_id  ip
1   2         127.0.0.1
2   1         127.0.0.1
3   2         127.0.0.1
```

Two times of `image_id` with value `2` and one time with value `1`.
I am trying to order the result like so:

```
user_contest_image.id user_contest_image.filename
2                     image_2.png
1                     image_1.png
```

I didn't provide example of my work because I really don't get how should I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your data seems you need  the order result for the image  vote

```
select user_contest_image.id , filename 
from  user_contest_image 
inner join  image_vote on image_vote.image_id = user_contest_image.id  
group by  user_contest_image.id, user_contest_image.file_name 
order by count(image_vote.image_id)  DESC
```

Comment: Well, thank you very much! Starting to explore the query now :D

Answer (score 2):

Join the tables, group by image id, add a `COUNT(image_vote.id)` field, and order by that field.